# Armstrong numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

```
num=int(input("please enter number: "))
for num in range(num, 1000):
    sum1=0
    numcp=num
    if(num>=10 and num<100):
        while(num>0):
            digit=int(num%10)
            d2=digit*digit
            sum1=sum1+d2
            num=int(num/10)

    if(num>=100 and num<1000):
        while(num>0):
            digit=int(num%10)
            d2=digit*digit*digit
            sum1=sum1+d2
            num=int(num/10)
    if(numcp==sum1):
        print("angstrong number: ", sum1)
```

what is wrong with this python code. it works till 407 then stops. i am unable to figure out why it stops when the range i have provided is 1000.

**Edited**

any other more pythonic way of doing this for number till 100000 or 1000000.

i don’t want to copy this if block ( if(num>=10 and num<100) ) many times which decides the number of digits.

Answer (score 2):

[Armstrong numbers](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap04/arms.html)? You seem to be right so far

> The following is the output from the above program. Thus, there are
>   six Armstrong numbers in the range of 0 and 999.
>   Armstrong numbers: 0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407

If you want to know if you reached the end you should probably put a

```
print(num)
```

after the loop

Comment: Always wanting your little code to be better than its predecessors :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a new way

```
n=list(map(int, raw_input()))

l=len(n)
sum=0
for i in n:
    sum=sum+pow(i,l)

sum=str(sum)
s=[]
for y in sum:
    s.append(int(y))

if(sorted(n)==sorted(s)):
    print('armstrong')
else:
    print('not armstrong')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple and readable to iterate over each character in a `String` with `Python`. If you convert the input number to a `String` it will make it  simple to iterate over the number digits and calculate whether a number is an [Armstrong Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number)

Check out this straightforward solution:

```
def armstrong_number(number):
    result = 0
    snumber = str(number)
    l = len(snumber)
    for digit in snumber:
        result += int(digit)**l
        if result > number:
            return False
    if result != number:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: You should include explanation for your code. Describing how and why this code solves the problem is more useful as it helps the OP and other readers solve this and similar issues themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine

```
a = input("Please enter a number: ")
t = 0
for i in a: t += int(i) ** len(a)
print(a, "Armstrong.") if t == int(a) else print(a, "Not Armstrong.")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
###### List Comprehension to find Armstrong Number ######

num = raw_input('Enter the number: ')

if sum([int(i) ** len(num) for i in num]) == int(num):
    print num, 'is a Armstrong number'
else:
    print num, 'is NOT Armstrong number'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Simple Armstrong Number Program in Python

```
n=input("Enter")
a=len(n)
s=0
x=0
c=int(n)
for i in range(0,a):
    x=int(n[i])
    s=s+x**a
if s==c:
    print("amstrong")
else:
    print("no")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do so is by list comprehension.
The following snippet generates the Armstrong numbers using list comprehension between the range 0 to 99999

```
print("armstrong a.k.a. narcissistic numbers : ")
armstrong = [x for x in range(100000) if sum(list(map(lambda y: y ** len(str(x)), list(map(int, str(x)))))) == x]
print(armstrong)
```

Output :

armstrong a.k.a. narcissistic numbers :

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208, 9474, 54748, 92727, 93084]

Answer (score 0):

***Armstrong Number Finder(Easy version)***

```
lst = []
number = int(input("Enter number: "))
sum1 = 0
a = number

while number>0:
    lst.append(number%10)
    number = number//10

for i in range(0,len(lst)):
    lst[i]=lst[i]**3
    sum1+=lst[i]

print(sum1)

if(sum1 == a):
    print("This is an armstrong number")
else:
    print("This is not an armstrong number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more golf code way:

```py
n = input("Please enter a number: ")
print(f"{n} is {'' if int(n) == sum(int(i)**len(n) for i in n) else 'not '}an Armstrong number")
```

Output for example n = 54748 and 1000:

```
# 54748 is an Armstrong number
# 1000 is not an Armstrong number
```

Answer (score 0):

### Armstrong Function- Basic one

```
def Armstrong(num):
    listt = []
    summ = 0
    for i in str(num):
        carry = pow(int(i),len(str(num)))
        listt.append(carry)
    for i in listt:
        summ = summ+i
    if num == summ:
        print(num , "is an Armstrong number")
    else:
        print(num , "is NOT an Armstrong number")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve it.

```
def getamstrong(n):
    val = [int(i) for i in str(n)]
    new = []
    for i in val:
        new.append(i**len(val))
    if sum(new) == n:
        print(f"{n} is an amstrong number")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is not an amstrong number")
        
n = 1634
getamstrong(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# The Below Function can display one number as an armstrong,
# or you could simply pass a range in the num_list to find all armstrong numbers in the 
# list.

def armStrong(num):
    number = str(num)
    digit = len(number)
    check = sum([int(i)**digit for i in number])
    if check==num:
        return "Armstrong"
    else:
        return "Not Armstrong"
print(armStrong(153))
num_list = [i for i in range(99800,100000)]
for i in num_list:
    print(f"{i} = {armStrong(i)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("please enter number: "))
def is_num_armstrong(num):
    total = 0
    for no in str(num):
        total += int(no)**len(str(num))
    if total == num:
        return True
    return False;
print("This is armstrong number." if is_num_armstrong(num) else "This is NOT armstrong number!!!")
#Print all armstrong numbers till 10000
#print([x for x in range(10000) if is_num_armstrong(x)])
```

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAYHd.png)#armstrong Numbers

Generate numbers between the range you want to check for existance of armstrong numbers

```
for x in range(100,1000):
    #Get the digits from the number generated as a, b, c
    a = x//100
    b = (x%100)//10
    c = x%10
    #now check whether the number is armstrong number or not
    #here, a**3 + b**3 + c**3 == abc
    if((a**3) + (b**3) + (c**3) == x):
        print("Armstrong Number {}".format(x))
```